# Real Time Morse code converter in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

After seeing Google's april fools joke of the morse code gmail, I thought I'd try to create a real-time morse code converter in javascript.

I'm using regex and replace to change the morse code into character. For example:

```
.replace(/.- /g, "a").replace(/.-. /g, "r")
```

The issue I'm having is that when I'm typing `.-.` for "r" it give me an "a" because it sees `.-` first.
How can I make it replace only exact matches?

**Updated** and working!! Thanks to every one that helped me

http://jsfiddle.net/EnigmaMaster/sPDHL/32/ - My Original code

http://jsfiddle.net/EnigmaMaster/LDKKE/6/  - Rewritten by Shawn Chin

http://jsfiddle.net/EnigmaMaster/y9A4Y/2/  - Rewritten by  Matthias Tylkowski

If anyone has other ways of writting this program please post a [JsFiddle](http://jsFiddle.net)

Id love to see how else this can be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers have already covered the reasons why your example was not working so I'll refrain from repeating them.

However, may I suggest that since you're already using spaces to delimit each code, a straight-forward solution would be to do a simple `.split()` to segment the input text into individual units then  simply do a one-to-one mapping of code to chars. 
This will be a lot more efficient than repeated regex replacements and less prone to errors.

For example:

```
var morse = {  // use object as a map
    '.-': 'a', 
    '-...': 'b', 
    '-.-.': 'c', 
    // .... the rest ...
};

function translate_morse(code) {  // given code, return matching char
    return (typeof morse[code] === "undefined") ? "" : morse[code];
    // if the var is not found, the code is unknown/invalid. Here we 
    // simply ignore it but you could print out the code verbatim and use
    // different font styles to indicate an erroneous code
}

// example usage
translated = code_text.split(" ").map(translate_morse).join("");
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/KGVAm/1/

p.s. I've taken the liberty of tweaking the code and the behaviour a little, i.e. disabling the input of other chars but allowing backscape to allow corrections.

Comment: Your awesome !!! Thank you so much . I couldnt figure out how to make the backspace work properly

Comment: I have another project you might find interesting that I need help with also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10229294/javascript-sticky-notes

Answer (score 3):

Your question highlights an interesting fact: **the Morse code is not a [prefix code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_code)**. So you need some kind of separator—spaces, commas, etc.—to delimit code symbols.

You seem to have decided to use spaces, that's fine.

This being said, what's missing in your regex is the escaping of the dot symbols (use `/\.- /` instead of `/.- /`)

Comment: Thank you that fixed part of the problem

Answer (score 3):

Another way of doing it is using a dichotomic search.

[image]

A graphical representation of the dichotomic search table: the user branches left at every dot and right at every dash until the character is finished.

Answer (score 1):

If you are handling one Morse character at a time, start with the longest sequences, down to the shorter ones.

Answer (score 1):

You should prioritize your rules and apply the replacement for the longer phrases first:

```
.replace(/\.-\./g,'r')// longer
.replace(/\.-/g,'a')// shorter
```

I suggest you make a dictionary and sort it by the pattern length and then replace the string:

```
var str = '.-.-.';
var dictionary = [
    ['a', '\.-'],
    ['r', '\.-\.']
    // ... and so on
];
dictionary
    .sort(function(a,b){
        return a[1] > b[1];
    })
    .forEach(function(el,i){
         str = str.replace(new RegExp(el[1],'g'),el[0]);
    });
```

Sry for the lack of brackets, I dont seem to find them on my phone.

**update** : i've escaped the dots used in the regular expressions - I missed that in the first place.
 **update2** : added brackets :)
You could use the unescaped dots in the dictionary and escape them on the fly :

```
 var dictionary = [
    ['a', '.-'],
    ['r', '.-.']
];
dictionary
    .sort(function(a,b){
        return a[1] > b[1];
    })
    .forEach(function(el,i){
         str = str.replace(new RegExp(el[1].replace(/([^\]\.)/g,'$1\.'),'g'),el[0]);
    });
```

Comment: most likely im just gonna prioritize the replacement like u suggested, it seems like an easier fix and is working so far, just have to test each letter out to see what needs to come before what

Comment: Do I really need to escape every period or will just the first one do it?

Comment: Unfortunately, you have to escape every period, but you can "automate" that too

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the "." characters:

```
/\.- /
```

instead of

```
/.- /
```

in other words. In a regular expression, "." matches any character.

Answer (score 1):

In regular expressions, the dot matches any character and it seems you are using it without proper scape:

```
/./  // this will match any character
/\./ // this will match a dot (".") character
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the trick here is to split the string that someone types into chunks. There should be a space after each sequence of "." and "-". Then you can run over that array and replace every entry with the corresponding letter. I would use a switch. In the end you join the array together as a string and display it.

Comment: Argh crap I forgot to save here is a working one: http://jsfiddle.net/vuPhp/3/
Anyway, your new version looks much more nice.

Comment: Thanks I posted your version at the top also

Answer (score 0):

For those who are seeking for the whole translation *table*:

[Here is a **demo**](http://tools.timodenk.com/morse-code-to-text) and here is the whole [**source** code](https://github.com/Simsso/Online-Tools/blob/master/page/logic/morse-code-to-text.js).

```
var morseCode = {
    '.-': 'a',
    '-...': 'b',
    '-.-.': 'c',
    '-..': 'd',
    '.': 'e',
    '..-.': 'f',
    '--.': 'g',
    '....': 'h',
    '..': 'i',
    '.---': 'j',
    '-.-': 'k',
    '.-..': 'l',
    '--': 'm',
    '-.': 'n',
    '---': 'o',
    '.--.': 'p',
    '--.-': 'q',
    '.-.': 'r',
    '...': 's',
    '-': 't',
    '..-': 'u',
    '...-': 'v',
    '.--': 'w',
    '-..-': 'x',
    '-.--': 'y',
    '--..': 'z',
    '-----': '0',
    '.----': '1',
    '..---': '2',
    '...--': '3',
    '....-': '4',
    '.....': '5',
    '-....': '6',
    '--...': '7',
    '---..': '8',
    '----.': '9',
    '.--.-': 'à',
    '.--.-': 'å',
    '.-.-': 'ä',
    '----': 'ch',
    '.-..-': 'è',
    '..-..': 'é',
    '---.': 'ö',
    '..--': 'ü',
    '...--..': 'ß',
    '--.--': 'ñ',
    '.-.-.-': '.',
    '--..--': ',',
    '---...': ':',
    '-.-.-.': ';',
    '..--..': '?',
    '-....-': '-',
    '..--.-': '_',
    '-.--.': '(',
    '-.--.-': ')',
    '.----.': '\'',
    '-...-': '=',
    '.-.-.': '+',
    '-..-.': '/',
    '.--.-.': '@'
};
```