# Javascript Sticky Notes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made some sticky notes in javascript for fun.

When there are multiple sticky notes on the screen, I want the one that is selected to be brought forward. IE. raise the z-index to be higher then the other sticky notes.
Currently I am doing this with CSS using :hover, which is kind of annoying. I want to do it in javascript/jquery. I tried to do addClass/removeClass with focus() and blur()

This is what I have so far

```
$('.darkYellow').click(function() {
    $(this).focus(function() {
        $(this).addClass("index");
    });
});

$('.darkYellow').blur(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("index");
});
```

**Updated** and Working thanks to Christoph
http://jsfiddle.net/EnigmaMaster/aQMhk/6/

Comment: The jsFiddle appears to be unrelated to this question.

Comment: @Quentin: the jsFiddle is obviously the CSS method which the questioner is trying to replace with a javascript one

Comment: I added the Javascript into the code and updated the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though at the moment I don't know, why `.on()` does not work (this shoud be the preferred method!), the following code should work:

```
$('.darkYellow').live("click", function() {
        $(".index").removeClass("index");
        $(this).addClass("index");
});
```

This is all you need.

1. live event handler on click ( use of on() should be preferred )
2. look for index note and remove class
3. add Class to current "clicked" element

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dL3kK/1/)**

Answer (score 8):

Class selectors start with a `.` character, class names do not (well, they can, but that way lies madness).

```
$(this).addClass("index")
```

Comment: (the phrase in brackets provided extra motivation for the up-vote ;-)

Comment: @EnigmaMaster: a) does the class actually get added to the element? (check via a DOM inspector tool such as firebug) b) what CSS have you assigned to .index?

Comment: No the class doesnt seem to be getting added, and i have z-index: 5; assigned to the css

Answer (score 2):

for addClass there is no need to include '.'

Simply

```
$(this).addClass("index");
```

http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `$('.darkYellow').click()` before the sticky notes actually exist. `.click()` will add an event to each element that matches the selector at the time of calling. What you want is something like [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) which will handle all elements, present and future E.g.

```
$('.darkYellow').live('click', function() {
    $(this).focus(function() {
        $(this).addClass("index");
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

Try:

```
$('.darkYellow').live('click', function() {
  $(this).addClass("index");
});

$('.darkYellow').live('blur', function() {
  $(this).removeClass("index");
});
```

As someone else pointed out, the call to .focus() should be unnecessary.

Comment: I'd like to avoid .live() if possible since "As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated." -from http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: @EnigmaMaster: Next sentence in the docs reads "Use .on() to attach event handlers." I must admit, I'm not familiar with `.on()` but it looks - in this simple case, at least - like a drop-in replacement for `.live()`. Give it a go and let us know how you get on.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `toggleFocus()` function I recently wrote, it's designed to add a `.is-focused` class the parentNode on focus/blur events.

[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/danielhaim1/pen/PoNompY)

```
function toggleFocus(e) {
    setTimeout(() => {
         e.addEventListener('focus', ({path}) => {
              path[2].classList.add("is-focused");
         }, true);

         e.addEventListener('blur', ({path}) => {
              path[2].classList.remove("is-focused");
         }, true);
    }, 0);
}

const items = document.getElementById('items');
const itemsArray = items.querySelectorAll(".item");

[].forEach.call(itemsArray, (item) => {
    toggleFocus(item)
});
```