# Text to morse code using jQuery

Tags: javascript, morse-code

I've been tasked with creating a little feature using JavaScript/jQuery that will translate text input by the user into morse code.

What would be the most efficient way of going about this?

Comment: You do not need jQuery: a simple dictionary of letters to their morse code is sufficient

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Real Time Morse code converter in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213760/real-time-morse-code-converter-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a hashmap like the one below should solve your problem, jQuery is unnecessary.

```
var morse={
    'a': '.-',
    'b': '-...',
    'c': ' -.-.'
    //etc, etc...
    'z': '--..'
}
```

Then you can get the morse values using `morse['a']`, substituting whatever key you need.

Comment: Any chance of a JSFiddle? Still confused on the usage, sorry!

Comment: calling `morse['a']` returns the value for `'a'` in the morse variable, which is `'.-'`.

Answer (score -2):

Use the jQuery `change()` method on text input field to act whenever the content changes.

Each time it changes, update a `<div>` element (or whatever) using the jQUery `html()` method.

Converting ASCII to morse code is a trivial substitution; you shouldn't need SO to help you with this.